# How can I check if sequence of numbers in an array is increasing by one, or more than one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers

```
let myNumbers = [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104];
```

I need to return `101` because it broke the sequence, it increased by two.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your `for` loop from the `1` to exclude existing checking.

```js
let myNumbers = [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104];

const findElement = arr => {
  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] - arr[i-1] > 1) {
      return arr[i]
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(findElement(myNumbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find` method and check if prev element is equal to current element - 1.

```js
let myNumbers = [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104];
let result = myNumbers.find((e, i, a) => i != 0 && e - 1 != a[i - 1]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That'll break if you have `0` in the array in the wrong place. Check `length` instead. (And: Wouldn't it be better to let the OP figure it out?)

Comment: `find` returns only first match, what if there are more numbers that break sequence?

Comment: @barbsan Not sure what result OP expects in that case, but yes find will return first match.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple `for` loop and check value of items.

```js
let myNumbers = [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104];
for(var i=0; i<myNumbers.length; i++)
  if (i!=0 && myNumbers[i]>0 && myNumbers[i]-1 != myNumbers[i-1])
    console.log(myNumbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myNumbers = [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104];

function incrementsBy(n, sequence) {
  let lastNumber = sequence[0]
  for(let n of sequence) {
    if(n - lastNumber > 1) return n
    lastNumber = n
  }
  return null
}

console.log(incrementsBy(1, myNumbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop as like below,

```js
function ShowBreak() {

  let myNumbers = [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 101, 102, 103, 104]

  for (i = 0; i < myNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
    
    var currentNo = myNumbers[i];
    var nextNo = myNumbers[i + 1];

    var differents = nextNo - currentNo;
    if (differents > 1) {
      console.log(nextNo);
      return alert("Sequence break on number " + nextNo + " by increase " + differents);
    }
  }
  return alert('Sequence not breaked.');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="ShowBreak()" value="Show" />
```